# Obter o nome de um arquivo e mostar em um Label

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um projeto e preciso que ao abrir uma (imagem) ele irá pegar o nome dessa imagem, salvar em uma variável e mostrar em uma da linha do excel.

**Obs.: Isso vai se repetir, serão vários arquivos que irei abrir..**

Então sei que preciso criar um foreach para ficar inserido uma nova linha para cada imagem nova que eu abrir. Outra forma é não salvar em um array e toda imagem que abrir limpar a variável.

Botão que abre a imagem:

```
private void openFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
try
{
string[] caminhoImagens = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\pedroduca\Pictures", "*.jpg");
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(caminhoImagens[0]);
string nomeArquivo = caminhoImagens[0];
NomeImagem.Text = nomeArquivo;

Bitmap image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
RFiltro1.Text = empty;
RFiltro2.Text = empty;
RFiltro3.Text = empty;

pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show($"Erro: {ex.Message}");
}
}
```

Aqui é o botão para gerar o excel:

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
Excel.Application AbreExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

if (AbreExcel == null)
{
MessageBox.Show("O Excel não está instalado corretamente!");
return;
}
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlWorkBook = AbreExcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Nome do arquivo";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Teste 1";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Teste 2";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Teste 3";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = Lstr_RFiltro1;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = Lstr_RFiltro2;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = Lstr_RFiltro3;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "**AQUI VAI O NOME DO ARQUIVO NA ARRAY**";

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\pedroduca\\Pictures\\TesteCaptcha.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
AbreExcel.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(AbreExcel);

MessageBox.Show("Excel criado com sucesso! ");
}
```

Peço desculpa pela mal formatação, sou novo no stackOverflow.

Comment: Mas afinal o que você quer fazer? O que tá acontecendo? Qual o problema?

Comment: Eu queria salvar o nome dos arquivos em um tipo de array e que fosse exibido em um Label. Fim das contas acabei salvando o nome dos arquivos, retirei o Label e salvei no Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você obrigatoriamente precisa passar o nome do arquivo para poder manipulá-lo.

No seu caso o que você pode fazer é obter os arquivos do diretório, e a partir disso filtrar e obter o arquivo que você quer.

Adiciona esse namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

E com o seguinte código, pegue as imagens no diretório que vc especificar:

```
string[] caminhoImagens = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Imagens\", "*.png",
                                     SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Com isso ele vai obter uma lista com o caminho completo de todas as imagens daquele diretório, por exemplo: c:\Imagens\imagem01.png - c:\Imagens\imagemPequena03.png

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Dei uma editada no código, cheguei a utilizar o código deu certo. Mas ele pegava o diretório do arquivo. No meu Label por exemplo ficava: C:\Users\pedroduca\Pictures\imagem1.png
E eu precisava que só ficasse imagem1. Consegui com o Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(caminhoImagens[0]);